# tensorflow>2.0 unavailable on conda-forge

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, mini-forge

I am attempting to create an environment from the github repostitory for CityNet, https://github.com/mdfirman/CityNet, but consistently get the following error:

ResolvePackageNotFound:tensorflow=2.4.1

I am using a miniforge terminal. My machine does not have anaconda installed.

Here is the environment file:

name: citynet
channels:

- default
- conda-forge
  dependencies:
- python=3.6
- numpy=1.19.5
- tensorflow=2.4.1
- pip
- pip:

  - pyyaml
  - tqdm==4.57.0
  - librosa==0.8.1
  - tf_slim==1.1.0
  - matplotlib==3.3.4

I have python 3.6 and python 3.10.12 installed. I am new-ish to python so please let me know what useful information I have not included.

I have tried using different versions of tensorflow and even forcing conda-forge like this:

conda-forge::tensorflow>=2.0,<=2.10

I attempted to install tensorflow and successfully did but it was in the pypi channel (tensorflow=2.15.0).

Comment: The error message indicates that there is a problem resolving the required version of TensorFlow (2.4.1).you can install TensorFlow directly from PyPI within your Conda environment using pip:
conda activate citynet
pip install tensorflow==2.4.1